# Postgresql count by past weeks

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

```
select id, wk0_count
from teams
left join
    (select team_id, count(team_id) as wk0_count
    from (
        select created_at, team_id, trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,created_at)) / 604800) as wk_offset
        from loan_files
        where loan_type <> 2
        order by created_at DESC) as t1
    where wk_offset = 0
    group by team_id) as t_wk0
on teams.id = t_wk0.team_id
```

I've created the query above that shows me how many loans each team did in a given week. Week 0 is the past seven days.

Ideally I want a table that shows how many loans each team did in the last 8 weeks, grouped by week. The output would look like:

[image]

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Mysql or postgresql?

Comment: @GurV Looks like Postgres to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    t.id,
    count(week = 0 or null) as wk0,
    count(week = 1 or null) as wk1,
    count(week = 2 or null) as wk2,
    count(week = 3 or null) as wk3
from
    teams t
    left join
    loan_files lf on lf.team_id = t.id and loan_type <> 2
    cross join lateral
    (select (current_date - created_at::date) / 7 as week) w
group by 1
```

In 9.4+ versions use the [aggregate filter syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
count(*) filter (where week = 0) as wk0,
```

`lateral` is from 9.3. In a previous version move the `week` expression to the filter condition.

Comment: Thanks - I'll dig more into aggregate filter synatx. Maybe this is the reason I get this error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date / integer
LINE 12:     (select current_date - lf.created_at::date / 7 as week) ...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @LancePoole Fixed

Comment: -quick question about the query. In teams table there are teams.id that don't appear in this query. Why is that? I've tried a left join, but that doesn't work. Ideally, the result would list every teams.id from teams.

Comment: @LancePoole For the `left join` to work it is necessary to move the `where` condition to the `join` condition. I edited the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following query?

```
SELECT team_id AS id, count(team_id) AS wk0_count
FROM teams LEFT JOIN loan_files ON teams.id = team_id
WHERE loan_type <> 2
  AND trunc(EXTRACT(epoch FROM age(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, created_at)) / 604800) = 0
GROUP BY team_id
```

Notable changes are:

- ORDER BY clause in subquery was pointless;
- created_at in innermost subquery was never used;
- wk_offset test is moved on the WHERE clause and not done in two distinct steps;
- outermost subquery was not needed.

Comment: Fabian - so would I do this query multiple times for each week I want in the output and then join those?